# Is this sentence correct or no?

Tags: american-english

I am being happy.
This sentence belongs to present continuous tense.
Can we show duration or state in present continuous tense or no? 
If we can?
By which structure?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, you can't say "I am being happy," but it is okay in special circumstances, to emphasize the sourcelessness of your good mood.  If a friend came upon you and saw a big smile on your face, but with no apparent reason for it, you could say "I'm just being happy."